# jQuery selector for a heading in $(this) div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I need to select and find the html value of the H2 tag within a particular div which is clicked, this is what I'm trying right now but to no avail:

When the .square is clicked, I'm trying to run this:

```
 $(this).find('h2').html();
```

and this is what the html looks like:

```
<div class="square" id="2"><h2>Title</h2><h3>Comment</h3></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you think you are doing something wrong? What happens? You also have to explain the problem you are facing, not only what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you assigning that to a variable, appending it, hiding it?

Comment: @FelixKling I tried to set the thing as a variable and alert() it but it's alerting 'undefined'

Comment: Please post a more complete example, preferably with http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. The code you posted is not enough to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code has to be placed inside a click handler like so:

```
$('.square').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).find('h2').html());
}
```

Outside of the click handler, `this` points to `window` and `$(window).find('h2')` doesn't find anything and thus `.html()` yields `undefined`.

If your `<div class="square">` is dynamically generated, you need to "hook" your click handler onto the closest element that will not disappear from the page.

```
$('#element_id').on('click', '.square', function() {
    alert($(this).find('h2').html());
}
```

Comment: I do currently have a click handler in place which is definitely working, it's  just returning 'undefined' for the h2.html :( The whole html thing is dynamically generated using javascript, does that change anything?

Comment: @Taimur Well, if the click handler fires but finds no items you have a different problem altogether. You should probably share more code with us.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to run the code after the document is ready.

```
$(function() {
    $(".square").click(function() {
        console.log($(this).find('h2').html());
    });
});
```

`$(function() {});` is the short way to write `$(document).ready(funciton() {});`.

Moreover your code has to be placed as callback of the click event listener.

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way for doing this is:

```
$('body').on('click', '.square', function(event) {
  var  html =  $(this).find('h2').html();
  console.log(html);
});
```

Comment: Because you delegate the event from the body, its faster

Comment: What is faster? The handling of the event? Doesn't it have to bubble up all the way up to `body` and then jQuery has to test whether it originated at a `.square` element and hence it is processed *slower*? Directly binding the event handler to the element itself avoids all this.

Comment: Nope, because it watches any clicks on body (so already on top) then tries to find .square

Comment: Events are processed in two phases, the capturing and the bubbling phase. jQuery only binds handler in the bubbling phase because IE (< 9 or 10) does not support capturing. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616704/218196. Which means, the closer you bind an event handler to the event's source element, the earlier it es executed. Event handlers bound at the top (`document`, `body`) are executed *last*. Don't get me wrong, I'm a big advocate of event delegation, but to claim that it is more efficient without knowing anything about the context and defining the term precisely is just misleading.

Comment: @borisrorsvort It's not faster at all. It **can** be more efficient when dealing with dynamic elements because there's only 1 event handler and less to worry about, but much more happens with this 1 click handler than with a single handler on each element.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is entirely correct. You may see an example of an application here (or on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwgDF/)):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div#2").click(function(){
        var title = $(this).find('h2').html();
        $("span").text(title);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="square" id="1"><h2>I'll not work because my id is 1</h2></div>
<div class="square" id="2"><h2>Click me and you'll see me below on the span!</h2></div>
<span></span>
```